# The bot sends a lot of messages - Discord.Py

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to create a command in discord.py that would later detect an additional message, but after correctly detecting the message, the bot doesn't know why it starts to spam, here's my code:

```
@client.command(aliases = ['dragon-panic'])
async def dp(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Welcome to the dragon panic. Scheme win is below. Drag 3 cards.\n" +
                    "\n Dragon Cards: Fire, Iron, Forest, Sea, Mountain")
    await ctx.send("Fire beats Forest\nFire beats Mountain\nForest beats Sea\nForest beats Iron" +
                    "\nSea beats Fire\nSea beats Mountain\nMountain beats Forest\nMountain beats Iron" +
                    "\nIron beats Fire\nIron beats Sea")
    dragon = ['fire', 'forest', 'sea', 'mountain', 'iron']
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        for i in "dragon":
            if 'Fire' in message.content:
                await ctx.send('You picked Fire Dragon')
                break
            elif 'Forest' in message.content:
                await ctx.send('You picked Forest Dragon')
                break
            elif 'Sea' in message.content:
                await ctx.send('You picked Sea Dragon')
                break
            elif 'Mountain' in message.content:
                await ctx.send('You picked Mountain Dragon')
                break
            elif 'Iron' in message.content:
                await ctx.send('You picked Iron Dragon')
            else:
                await ctx.send('No dragon with that name!')
                break
            break
```

Comment: why did you put an event inside a command? That's not how it works. You should use `wait_for`, not that weird thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Łukasz Kwieciński pointed out, don't put an event inside a command; your `on_message` event should stand alone outside any command. Instead, you should use `wait_for`. Replace your code with this, it should work without errors:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ['dragon-panic'])
async def dp(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Welcome to the dragon panic. Scheme win is below. Drag 3 cards.\n" +
                    "\n Dragon Cards: Fire, Iron, Forest, Sea, Mountain")
    await ctx.send("Fire beats Forest\nFire beats Mountain\nForest beats Sea\nForest beats Iron" +
                    "\nSea beats Fire\nSea beats Mountain\nMountain beats Forest\nMountain beats Iron" +
                    "\nIron beats Fire\nIron beats Sea")
    dragon = ['Fire', 'Forest', 'Sea', 'Mountain', 'Iron']
    def check(m):
        return m.channel == ctx.channel and m.author == ctx.author
    try:
       message = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=7.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send('Dragon not picked in time')
    else:
        for i in dragon:
            if i.lower() in message.content.lower():
                await ctx.send(f'You picked {i} Dragon')
                break
        else:
            await ctx.send('No dragon with that name!')
```

The `timeout=7.0` acts to put a restraint on how long the command will wait for the next message - in this case, 7 seconds. You can modify it to your own time value. In this example, if the user doesn't respond in 7 seconds, then the bot will print out `Dragon not picked in time`.